# Find the function continuous or discontinuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

$\sum_{n=1}^∞ $ $(x+2)^n \over n! + x^2$      ,  Interval = [1,2]

Is this function continuous in that interval ? I tried but the factorials are troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this makes sense in applying the Weierstrass M test.

We have that

$$ \left| \frac{(x+2)^n}{n!+x^2} \right| \leq \frac{4^n}{n!+1} \leq \frac{4^n}{n!}$$

Where we know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{n!} = e^4-1$, so that your sum converges uniformly on $[1,2]$. Now each partial sum is a continuous function which implies that the limit function is a continuous function as well.

I'm pretty sure you can extend this to continuity on $[a,b]$ to show that it's continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood very well (: